# Can I replace a character in a String using foo.charAt(i)?

Tags: java

I am trying to replace vowels in a String with numbers in succession resetting at 9. What is the correct way to do this? This is the only idea I have at the monent:

```
word.charAt(i)=vowelcount;
vowelcount++;
```

The above is in a for loop. word is a String and vowelcount is a char who starts with a value of 48 and resets to that at 57.

But that gives me the error:

> required: variable
>
> found:    value

What is the correct way to replace vowels in a String with an int that counts in succession?

> Sample input: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
>
> Sample output: Th0 q12ck br3wn f4x j5mps 6v7r th8 l9zy d0g.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so no. You have to construct a new String object with the modified character.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a stringbuilder for this.

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
```

and use

```
myString.setCharAt();
```

Answer (score 0):

`String`s in Java are immutable.
That means that their value cannot be changed, once they are instantiated.
The correct way to replace a character on a `String` is to create another `String`, made of whatever comes before, the character you mean to replace, and whatever comes after.
I'll leave the code implementation to the reader, as it looks like you're learning Java, and that would be a good exercise for you.

In your specific case, you want to iterate a `String`, and build another one, so it's worth looking into the `StringBuilder` class.

As additional context, `word.charAt(i)` in Java is an expression, and expressions are not assignable. That would be the same as doing

```
3 = 4;
```

You can only assign to variables (of any type) or array locations.
If your string was a char[], for example, you could have done

```
word[i] = vowelcount;
```

This actually gives you another way of implementing what you want. Transform your `String` into a `char[]`, and then back to `String` when you're done. See methods [String.toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) and constructor [String(char[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])).